# How to do calculation in ng2-smart-table(angular2)

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-forms, angular2-services, ng2-smart-table

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIGKp.png[i need to find the amount and subtotal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyLAU.png)

i need to calculate (qty*price)two columns values and store the result  into another column(amount)  of the ng2-smart-table

Comment: please click the "i need to find the amount and total" then only clearly understand my question.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: The question is not clear?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very smooth method to choose this problem

```
Total:{
    title: 'Total',
    valuePrepareFunction :(cell, row) =>{
        return row.quantity * row.productPrice;
   } 
  }
```